# Using a UIWebView as a way to update our business app quickly

Tags: iphone

We are looking at building a b2b application for the iPhone. A major concern is the possible delay in publishing updates to the applications. I would like to believe that all updates will be orderly, but the reality of a newly found bug for a client or an upcoming trade show could mean that updating the application NOW is critical. Even an "expedited" day wait would not be acceptable.

One option I have thought of is having a flag for each page that we send down when the user logs into our server. If the flag is set, then instead of the native screen for a given page, there would be a page with a UIWebView that would get the latest HTML from the web or stored HTML loaded at the time of login.

I would prefer storing the HTML and using it "offline" because a data connection cannot be guaranteed.

The questions are:

1) Does this violate any of Apple's licensing?

2) Is this feasible or is there a hole I am not thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesnt violate Apple's guidelines and as far as I know you are not missing anything here...in fact, we have the exact same problem in my company (which on top of the issue that you have, we have customers that would like to "brand" the app for their users, and thats how we accomplish that) and there are no issues with apple (for now...:)). Obviously, you need to think of user experience implications...hope that helps.